# Неявная прямая речь с МЫСЛЬЮ автора

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация, несобственно-прямая-речь

Как правильно записать МЫСЛЬ автора:

1. Я понял одно: "Вы все умрете".
2. Я понял одно: "вы все умрете".
3. Я понял одно: вы все умрете.
4. Иной вариант.

З.Ы. *Подчеркиваю:* мне крайней важно писать мысли в кавычках, если это допускается пунктуацией.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов два.  **(1) Я понял одно: вы все умрете. (2) Я понял одно –  вы все умрете.**

Бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) с изъяснительным значением.

Это **не  дословное высказывание**, для оформления по образцу прямой речи (кавычки, прописная буква) **нет оснований.**

Варианты различаются **интонацией и смысловыми оттенками.** Предложение (2) читается с укороченной паузой, логическим ударением выделена вторая часть.

Или так: **Я подумал: "Вы все умрете, это ясно".**

Comment: А как тогда писать:

Я подумал: "Вы все умрете"? 

Так?

Comment: Я подумал: "Вы все умрете".  Это обычное оформление прямой речи.

Comment: Странно, 
Я подумал: "Вы все умрете". –  это прямая речь следовательно может оформляться в скобки и писаться с большой буквы.
а  
Я понял одно: "Вы все умрете". –  прямой речью быть не может, поэтому пишется:
Я понял одно: вы все умрете или Я понял одно – вы все умрете.
Голова моя набекрень...

Comment: Глаголы «понять и подумать»  имеют разную семантику. Понять – это обдумать тему и сделать вывод, который имеет форму предложения с изъяснительным значением, но это именно вывод, а не конкретно сказанная мысль.  Подумать – это практически сказать что-то, но только не вслух, поэтому «я подумал» подходит в качестве слов автора при оформлении прямой речи, а «я понял» – не подходит. Но для «я подумал» существует другое оформление – в виде БСП, но изъяснительная часть при этом не считается прямым высказыванием. Чтобы мысль (я подумал) была похожа на вывод (я понял), я добавила слова «это ясно».

Comment: Чтобы решить вашу проблему, нужно понять ситуацию, знать контекст.   Существуют способы упрощенного оформления прямого высказывания, заключенного в кавычки, когда прямая речь является членом предложения. Например:  Мысль «Вы все умрете» промелькнула в моем сознании.  Это прямое высказывание в роли несогласованного определения (мысль какая).